# Hide Android App from Task manager

Tags: java, android, taskmanager

is there is a way to hide android app from Android 4 default task manager

[image]

i don't want the user to see my app in the list

any ideas ?

Answer (score 8):

Add this to the Activity tag of the Activity in Manifest file, that you don't want to show up in the recent apps list:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude):

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is,
>   when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute
>   determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent
>   apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set
>   "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

Comment: Didn't work for me in Android 4.3.